# How to add zend form element at specific position?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form-element, zend-form2

I have created an abstract form class that adds a `submit` element to the form. When my other form classes extend this form class I am having to call `parent::__construct()` at the bottom of the class so that the submit element is added last.

How do I set the submit button to always be the last element in the form, event if I call `parent::__construct()` first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form `add` function accepts two parameters - either an array or element instance, and an array of `flags`. One of the flag options is `priority`. The smaller the number, the lower in the list of elements it will appear. Therefore, setting it to -1000 (unless you have greater than 1000 elements) will set the submit button to appear at the bottom of the form:

```
$this->add([
    'name' => 'submit',
    'type' => 'submit',
    'attributes' => [
        'value' => 'Submit',
        'class' => 'btn btn-sm',
    ],
    'options' => []
],
[ 'priority' => -1000 ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

RichardParanby-King's answer is good but careful for the view :

In the view we have a lot of options to show the form :

- `<?= $this->form($form)?>`
- `<?= $form->get('{element}') ?>`
- loop over `$form->getIterator()`
- loop over `$form->getElements()`

etc...

I have to say I used a lot this structure in all of my projects :

```
<?php foreach ($form->get('fieldset')->getElements()  as $elementName => $element): ?>
     <?= $this->partial('partial/formElement', ['element' => $element])?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

The problem is : getElements does not use priority, so its just give the element in order of when it was instanciated.

In the view we have to use the iteration method (`$form->getIterator()`) to get back this priority.